# Draw Arc Between Two Points with Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I want to use Python Turtle to draw an arc between two points.

The turtle module allows something like `turtle.circle(200, 180)` but this is very limited, as I want to control the orientation of the arc as well.

I see that Tkinter has something that does this:

```
from Tkinter import *

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)                

canvas.create_arc(200, 200, 300, 100)


widget = Label(canvas, text='AAA', fg='white', bg='black')
widget.pack()
canvas.create_window(100, 100, window=widget)     
mainloop()
```

but I can't work out how to get this to work with just Turtle. I expect there are several possible solutions. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Which one of the infinitely many arcs that connect two points?

Comment: The one which is a part of the circle with a given radius, as in the first example. More specifically I want to be able to give radius and angle and then draw the arc at a given orientation. The two point thing was just one approach. I could set heading before the circle command, but that gets confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by orientation?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use Python Turtle to draw an arc between two points.

Your Tkinter example isn't drawing an arc between two arbitrary points -- it's using your points to define a rectangle and drawing a section of the oval bound by that rectangle.  Given that you defined a square, that can be emulated by Python Turtle:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def create_arc(turtle, x1, y1, x2, y2, start=0, extent=90):

    radius = min(abs(x2 - x1), abs(y2 - y1)) / 2
    cx, cy = x1 + (x2 - x1) / 2, y1 + (y2 - y1) / 2

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setposition(max(x1, x2), cy)
    turtle.setheading(90)
    turtle.circle(radius, extent=start)
    position = turtle.position()

    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(radius, extent=extent)
    turtle.setposition(cx, cy)
    turtle.setposition(position)

canvas = Screen()
canvas.setup(312, 312)  # adjust for borders
canvas.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, 306, 306)

tortoise = Turtle(visible=False)

create_arc(tortoise, 200, 200, 300, 100)

canvas.mainloop()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Arbitrary arcs can be tricky in Python Turtle but don't assume that you can't do it until you've clearly define what kinds of arcs you need and have made an attempt to program it.